# Django: Cannot get value of model form in templates

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new in using Django. I want to get data from model form by giving spcific id to model and show that data in a template. But I could not send value to template. I am getting nothing in template. Here is my code:

```
def store_id(request,id):
    dev_games = GamesModel.objects.get(id=id)
    form = GameForm(instance=dev_games)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request,'Developer/developed_games.html',{'form_data': form, 'user': request.user}
```

)

```
 <div id="Edit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="#" class="form-signin">
                        <h1 class="form-signin-heading">Modify game</h1>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table class="spaced_table modal_table">
                            {{form_data}} #could not get value here
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Edit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense; HttpResponseRedirect does not render a template, it redirects to another URL. Please post your exact code.

Comment: Also, assuming you did actually put `render`, why are you only passing `form.instance` to the template and not the form itself? `form.instance` is the exact same thing as `dev_games`, so what's the point of the form?

Comment: Yeah Made a mistake there but I am not also getting the value if I have form instead of form.instance